# How to index and plot two graphs

Tags: python, plot, indexing, dataset

Probably a beginner's question, but I can't figure out how to index correctly and get a plot per date in Python. I have a list of dates, and for each date I want to plot 2 curves with four values.

[image: Extract of dataset]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use myplotlib library and change the number of variables:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as p
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [67.28,67.01,66.99,67.5]
x1= [0,1,2,3]
y1= [109,112,230,321]
p.sublot(211) # 2 - number of rows, 1 - number of columns, 1 - plot number
p.plot(x,y)
p.plot(x1,y1)
p.subplot(212)
p.plot(x,y)
p.plot(x1,y1)
p.show()
```

You can get some more information on how to plot here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py

Comment: Thanks. My biggest issue is really how to change the variable amounts in a script - with a nested loop? The dataset is huge...

Comment: next variables u have to insert manually with prefixes x,x1,x2,x3 etc. to separate data, u have to use subplot